# Is There Any Way to Farm XP During Post-Game Play?

Tags: infamous

I'm trying to unlock the trophy **True Hero** - *Purchase every positive Karma upgrade for each power* on hard difficulty. I've completed all of the story missions and I'm about 8000 XP short for the remaining upgrades.

Is there any *reasonable* way to grind XP during post-game play so that I can get this trophy without having to play through the game again? Keep in mind that on hard mode your enemies reward you with much less XP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, remember that in order to gain all good karma powers, you need to choose to do all the good side missions instead of the bad.

If you have a save a few missions before the end boss, I recommend loading it and replaying the last missions, I remember a mission very close to where end boss is located where large groups of enemies were fighting each other. I kept playing the mission, killing the large enemies then killing myself - the XP stayed. It took me a chunk of time but I managed to gain enough XP for the last upgrades.

If you're past that mission, I recommend you collect shards and dead drops, complete side missions, capture zones and perform stunts. If you find these method still don't provide enough XP, try lowering the difficulty in the settings.

Also worth noting, if you downloaded the free DLC power (the blade melee weapon), you don't need to buy it to get the upgrades trophy, so focus on getting the good side powers first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I'm all out of side-missions. I have literally nothing left to do in the game apart from wander around and collect dead drops & blast shards. So I need any other way to gain experience. I suppose I could heal civilians...but that's about 4000 people healed to reach my goal =/ And do shards / dead drops reward experience?

Comment: Shards and dead drops do give some XP, as well as performing stunts. I recommend you use a map to collect shards though and cross off the ones you've collected. Collecting the last few was really annoying for me.